# MySQL but don't know the column names before hand

Tags: php, mysql

I am building an PHP/MySQL app and I am allowing users to create their own custom (as much as they want) profile data  (i.e. they can add any amount of info to their profile with additional textboxes, but there is a "CORE" set of user profile fields)

For example, they can create a new textbox on the form and call it "my pet" and/or "my favorite color". We need to store this data in a database and cannot obviously create columns for each of their choices since we don't know what their additional info is before hand.

One way we think that we could store all "addidional info" they provide is to store their additional info as JSON and store it in a MySQL text field ( I love MySQL :) )

I've seen Wordpress form builder plugins where you can create your own fields so I'm thinking they must store the data in MySQL somehow as NoSQL solutions are beyond the scope of these plugins.

I would love to stick with MySQL but do you guys think NoSQL solutions like MongoDB/Redis would be a better fix since for this?

Thanks

Comment: The answer, as ever, is _it depends_. If you've hundreds of thousands of users you would need to try a variety of solutions to see what will scale. But, for a small set of options for a relatively small set of rows, JSON or a serialised PHP value, in your existing relational db, is fine. I think Wordpress uses serialisation internally for some of its options records.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question and a nice feature :-)

Answer (score 3):

One way to approach this is to use a single table using the EAV paradigm, or Entity-Attribute-Value.  See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).  That would be far tidier in most respects than letting users choose a database schema.

Comment: Looks really interesting and the intro seems to solve my problem... is this native to MySQL or a design paradigm?

Comment: It is a natural fit for any relational database.  It could be used in spreadsheet too, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a table of key value pairs where anything not in core would be stored.  The table would look like:  user_id, name_of_user_specified_field, user_specified_value;

Any name_of_user_specified_field that starts showing up a lot you could then add to the core table.  This is referred to as Entity-Attribute-Value. Please note, some people consider this an anti-pattern.

If you do this, please add controls to limit the number of new entries a user can create or  you might find someone stuffing your db with lots of fields :)

Comment: Thanks Ray never thought of this, but it may ??? get massive if a lot of users with a lot of custom fields? What do you think?

Comment: @BillJobs yep, that's why you need to impose some limit, like a user can only create up to 10 custom fields.

Comment: Very very true, a limit would make sense for "custom data"

Comment: Funnt thing is I expected ppl to say "MySQL sucks, NoSQL solutions are exactly what you are looking for" since "column names" are not enforced... No the case... recommend sticking with MySQL and all the solutions provided (Thanks) or using MongoDB just for this data and pulling it in?

Comment: @BillJobs For this limited case I don't have enough details to tell you whether a relational or a non-relational DB's is your best option.  IF you've willing to put up full details about your current schema, your core use cases, and reporting needs in a new question you could probably solicit a lot of good recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can handle this just fine.  If the additional data is always going to be pulled out all together (i.e. you will never need to get just the pet field without any other additional fields) then you can store it serialized in a column on the users table.  However, if you want a more relational model, you can store the extra data in a separate table linked by the user ID.  The additional table would have a column for the user ID, additional field name additional field value, and whatever else you might want with it.  Then you just run a `JOIN` query when getting the profile to get all of the extra fields.

Comment: Thanks for the reply G-Nugget, is serialized my only option when I don't know the column names before hand?

Comment: @BillJobs No, you can just insert a new row into the additional info table with the new field name and value.